# rack awarness configuration not working

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm working with Hadoop Paradigm and i want to configure the rack awarness files.

So i've created a topology.sh script and topology.data file and i populated it with my nodes.

But when i start my cluster and type hadoop dfsadmin -report command it doesn't show the rack of any node.

Can any one help me with this.

here are my topology.sh script

```
HADOOP_CONF=/usr/local/hadoop/conf
while [ $# -gt 0 ] ; do
nodeArg=$1

exec< ${HADOOP_CONF}/topology.data
result=””
while read line ; do

ar=( $line )

if [ "${ar[0]}” = “$nodeArg” ] ; then

result=”${ar[1]}”

fi
done
shift
if [ -z "$result" ] ; then
echo -n “/default/rack “
else
echo -n “$result “
fi

done
```

and the topology.data file

```
master  /rack1
slave1  /rack1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess this shouldn't be in your script...

> Unlock the rest of this book.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the topology.sh script, i just gave the shell permission to execute the script with chmod 755 topology.sh, and it works perfectly now.

Thanks all.